# What is the best place to retrive ViewPager child's layout?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Good morning,

I have a Fragment which its layout has a ViewPager, I provide a custom PageAdapter to show two child layouts. One layout is to fill with personal data and another layout is to fill with Address data by the user. On my fragment I want to retrieve both layouts data and fill a object Pessoa(Person) with an attribute Endereco (Address). So far my ViewPager is working and both layout are displayed, however when I try to get the fields on both layouts, either on onCreateView or onResume fragment's method, using :

`viewpager.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.txt1)`

I got an NullPointerException, but if I add an OnPageChangeListener this works, I not sure if it's the best approach. Is There a best place to retrieve a reference to the viewpager child's layout?

Ps. I don't want to use two other Fragments in order to display each of the layouts.

PageAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerCadastroPessoaAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private int[] views = {R.layout.layout_cadastro_dados_pessoais,R.layout.layout_cadastro_endereco };

public ViewPagerCadastroPessoaAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(views[position], container, false);
    container.addView(layout, position);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return "Dados Pessoais";
        case 1:
            return "Endereço";
    }
    return super.getPageTitle(position);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}}
```

ViewPager's holder Fragment

```
public class CadastroPessoaFragment extends Fragment {
    private ViewPager viewPagerCadastroPessoa;
    private TabLayout tabLayoutCadastroPessoa;

    public CadastroPessoaFragment() {
    }

    public static CadastroPessoaFragment newInstance() {
        return new CadastroPessoaFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cadastro_pessoa, container, false);

        tabLayoutCadastroPessoa = root.findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutCadastroPessoa);
        viewPagerCadastroPessoa = root.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCadastroPessoa);

        viewPagerCadastroPessoa.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewPagerCadastroPessoa.setAdapter(new ViewPagerCadastroPessoaAdapter(getContext()));
        tabLayoutCadastroPessoa.setupWithViewPager(viewPagerCadastroPessoa);

        int cor = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.white);
        tabLayoutCadastroPessoa.setTabTextColors(cor, cor);

        //get a null pointer
        viewPagerCadastroPessoa.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.txt1);

        viewPagerCadastroPessoa.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //works fine
                viewPagerCadastroPessoa.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.txt1);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        return  root;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //get a null pointer
        viewPagerCadastroPessoa.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.txt1); 
    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance

**UPDATE**
According with

> Anton Malyshev answer
>   The way Viewpager creates its pages is kind of "unsynchronized", so I used the following approach to solve my problem:

On my custom adapter I definied an interface with a single method onViewPagerReady(), as my Viewpager will always have only two pages, inside instantiateItem I check when position is 1 (once position starts with 0), if position == 1 I call the method onViewPagerReady that my fragment viewpager's holder implements, so inside this method I retrieve the layout of viewpager's children

```
public class ViewPagerCadastroPessoaAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public interface ViewPagerObserver{
        void onViewPagerReady();
    }

    private Context context;
    private int[] views = {R.layout.layout_cadastro_dados_pessoais,R.layout.layout_cadastro_endereco };
    private ViewPagerObserver observer;

    public ViewPagerCadastroPessoaAdapter(Context context, ViewPagerObserver observer) {
        this.context = context;
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(views[position], container, false);
        container.addView(layout, position);

        if(position == 1){
            observer.onViewPagerReady();
        }
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return "Dados Pessoais";
            case 1:
                return "Endereço";
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

Fragment Viewpager's Holder

```
@Override
    public void onViewPagerReady() {
        View rootCadastroDadosPessoais = viewPagerCadastroPessoa.getChildAt(0);
        View rootCadastroEnderecos =viewPagerCadastroPessoa.getChildAt(1);
    }
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Just wait until `viewPagerCadastroPessoa.getChildCount()` will be greater than 0. The pages in ViewPager are not created yet in `onResume` (they are created asynchronously).

Comment: Thanks to your answer I tried the following approach and it seems to work. I use kind of an Observer pattern in which my adapter notify my fragment that it's done.